# There are 12 students in a class. Find the number of n ways so that the student can take tests if 4 students are to take each test.

Tags: probability

There are 12 students in a class.  Find the number of n ways so that the student can take tests if 4 students are to take each test.

I tried to answer this but I think that my answer is very wrong. My solution is
$$\frac{12!}{(12-3)!3!}\frac{12!}{(12-4)!4!}.$$

I did my best but I think this is not the correct answer, please help me with this

Comment: How many tests? (4 students are to take each test: how many tests?)

Comment: 12 students, 4 students each test, which means there are three tests. First you take 4 students for the first one (12 choose 4), and then (8 choose 4), and (4 choose 4). The problem is that it might be double counting here, Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, I understand now. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 2):

I think that your thought is good. First you choose $4$ students out of $12$, then for the second group you choose $4$ students out of $8$ and the at last $4$ students out of $4$. But as you've mentioned it can lead to double counting.

So we calculate:

$$\binom{12}{4} \times \binom{8}{4} \times \binom{4}{4}$$

But instead of dividing with $3$, you should divide by $6$, because the number of permutations of $3$ is $6$. Here's example:

Let studnets from $1-4$ be in the first group, $5-8$ in the second and $9-12$ in the third.

We have $6$ permutations.

$$A = {1,2,3,4} \quad B = {5,6,7,8} \quad C = {9,10,11,12}$$
$$A = {1,2,3,4} \quad B = {9,10,11,12} \quad C = {5,6,7,8}$$
$$A = {5,6,7,8} \quad B = {1,2,3,4} \quad C = {9,10,11,12}$$
$$A = {5,6,7,8} \quad B = {9,10,11,12} \quad C = {5,6,7,8}$$
$$A = {9,10,11,12} \quad B = {1,2,3,4} \quad C = {5,6,7,8}$$
$$A = {9,10,11,12} \quad B = {5,6,7,8} \quad C = {1,2,3,4}$$

This 6 example are completely the same, but using our formula for generating number of ways we obtain all of them, so we have to divide by $6$.

So the number of ways is:

$$n = \frac{\binom{12}{4} \times \binom{8}{4} \times \binom{4}{4}}{3!}$$
$$n = \frac{495 \times 70 \times 1}{6}$$
$$n = 5775\text{ ways}$$

Comment: Please read the OPs comment below his/her question for clarification as to the problem statement.

Comment: I've edited the answer. Hope you can look at it and tell if it's OK

Comment: Way to go, my friend!

Comment: Actually, I don't think we divide by $6!$ because under your grouping, we have distinct tests A, B, C, so who's in A, who's taking B, who's taking C does matter.

Comment: Nice thought, but I think it's all about the grouping, because the OP said something about double counting, otherwise there won't be a double counting. So I hope that OP will tell whether A,B and C are distinct test.

Comment: Why would they be grouped into groups of four if the tests were not distinct? Otherwise, 12 students would be taking the same test and there'd be no point to grouping.

Comment: Let's think like this. 12 students take maths test and they are divided into 3 classrooms. It doesn't matter which group is in which classroom, as long the group contains same students. Then in this case my reasoning is right. So that's what I say let's OP tell wheter A,B and C are distinct tests.

Answer (score 2):

This looks to me like a [multinomial problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_coefficient): we can work with $\binom{12}{4,  4, 4}$ since three groups of four students (total 12) are testing.

The multinomial coefficient $$\binom{12}{4, 4, 4} = \dfrac{12!}{4!4!4!} = 34650$$ ways that 12 students can be grouped into groups of $4$ to take one of 3 specific tests: $4$ taking test 1, $4$ taking test 2, and $4$ taking test 3.

There is no double counting because each group is taking a different test: there are three distinct tests, after all.

Comment: this is the correct answer according to our teacher

Comment: @user93906 You can *accept* the answer (mark it "correct") by clicking on the check mark (in grey) $\large \checkmark$ to the left of the answer. (Your the only one that can do that.) It turns green when you click on it. You can check mark one answer per question asked.

Answer (score 0):

** It's an attempt only! **

12 students, 4 students each test, which means there are three tests. First you take 4 students for the first one (12 choose 4), and then (8 choose 4), and (4 choose 4).

Now that the groups are determined, we need to assign each group to a test, for that we have 3! = 6 options for each group selection.

Though in order to avoid double counting in the group selection, we divide by 3 because the groups can be chosen in a different order.

Finally, it's  $12\choose 4$ * $8\choose4 $* $4 \choose 4$ $ * 2 $